# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (22640,32) into shape (22639,32)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, audio-processing

I am working with audio files. After feature extraction, I want to convert a Tensor into a numpy array but I am getting the following error:

"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (22640,32) into shape (22639,32)"

A small portion of my code is:

```
X = []
Y = []
print("Feature Extraction Started")
for i,class_list in enumerate(data_list): #datalist = all files, class list = folder name in datalist, sample = path to the audio file in that particular class list
  for j,samples in enumerate(class_list):    #samples are of the form classes_name/audio file
    if(samples.endswith('.wav')):
      sample_rate,audio = wavfile.read(os.path.join(dire,samples))
      if(audio.size<16000):
        audio = np.pad(audio,(16000-audio.size,0),mode="constant")
      coeff = MFCCwithpaddingfunction.mfcc(audio,sample_rate,0.985) # 0.985 = preemphasis
      X.append(coeff)
      if(samples.split('/')[0] in classes):
        Y.append(samples.split('/')[0])
      elif(samples.split('/')[0]=='_background_noise_'):
        Y.append('silence')
#X= coefficient array and Y = name of the class

A = np.zeros((len(X),len(X[0]),len(X[0][0])),dtype='float32')
print("A shape:",len(X),len(X[0]),len(X[0][0]))
for i in range(0,len(X)):
  A[i] = np.array(X[i])      #Converting list X into array A
```

Can anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just do `A = np.array(X)` ?

Comment: Thanks, this worked!